No puedo hacer que cumpla el if
Tengo una consulta :
SELECT COUNT(bd.alumnos_datos_ubicacion.id_alumno_datos_ubicacion) AS VALOR
FROM  bd.alumnos_datos_ubicacion
WHERE bd.alumnos_datos_ubicacion.id_alumno= 'xxxxx' AND bd.alumnos_datos_ubicacion.id_localidad = 'xxxxxxxxxx' 

Esto me regresa ya sea un 1 si encuentra el registro o un 0 en caso contrario, y estos valores los quiero utilizar para realizar unas operaciones. En caso de que encuentre un registro según las condiciones del where, entonces solo debo actualizar, pero si no encuentra un registro entonces debería insertar información en la tabla.
Al final de la consulta estoy haciendo esto:
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta) or die
             $valor = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
             $num = $valor['VALOR'];
             echo $num;  <--- Aquí me regresa ya sea 1 o 0 es temporal para visualización del dato que se obtiene//
             if($num == 1)
                {return TRUE;}
             elseif ($num == 0)
                {return FALSE;}
        }

Entonces en otra sección de código estoy haciendo esto:
 if($this->consulta_dgenerales() == FALSE ){
                $this->guardar_generales();  //inserta datos 
                $this->actualizar_g();   //actualiza un campo en base a lo insertado
                } elseif($this->consulta_dgenerales() == TRUE ) {
                $this->actualizar_a(); // actualiza datos previamente capturados
                $this->actualizar_g(); // actualiza un campo en base a la actualizacion
                }

El detalle es que funciona a medias, en ocasiones en la primer pasada de prueba, sí lleva a cabo las instrucciones del TRUE, pero si repito la operación sobre el mismo registro no hace el false, sino que vuelven a hacer un true e inserta los registros; en otro momento sí toma el valor que corresponde y hace el update, pero si intento hacer otra actualización entonces hace una inserción y se duplican los registros insertados o triplican según la cantidad de operaciones que se hagan de prueba.
Sé que me falta algo que no he logrado identificar.

¿Estás usando mysql_* ?. Estas instrucciones fueron declaradas obsoletas desde PHP 5.5 y removidas en PHP 7.x (ambas versiones sin soporte actual). A menos que estés manteniendo un código legado, lo cual deberías especificar, en su lugar usar mysqli_* o PDO.

@aeportugal Si efectivamente es un código que tiene como 12 o mas  años de antigüedad el cual por cuestiones técnicas no se ha podido migrar a una  versión de PHP mas reciente,  y si es una versión anterior de PHP 5.5 , tiene muchos detalles,  muchas partes del código utiliza mysql, en otras secciones tiene mysqli y en actualizaciones ya sea ha integrado con PDO es un franky... funcional.

No podrías plantear una consulta como select * from tabla where condition limit 1? Así aseguras que si tienes registro lo actualizas, y si no tienes lo creas... Parece muy rebuscado mirar un conteo de "existencia" para luego tener que actualizar o crear...

@Jakala Me parece una buena idea lo que mencionas, es otra manera de verificar un registro,  hago el análisis de lo que necesito , lo implemento y  te comento en que me trabo.  Saludos.   Gracias.

@Jakala no es rebuscado en absoluto. De hecho, en la mayoría de los casos un SELECT COUNT es más rápido que un SELECT *. Ver por ejemplo aquí y aquí

De acuerdo con eso si fuera para hacer otro tipo de operaciones (por ej un count de paginación) pero si directamente tiene que editar o crear el objeto ese en concreto? (Al menos es lo que parece)

@Jakala aún en ese caso, se supone que el criterio que se use en el WHERE el cual ya se tiene de antemano, es lo único necesario para identificar el o los datos que se están buscando. En un UPDATE nunca necesitas los mismos datos que ya existen para hacer la actualización (por eso un SELECT * no tiene sentido ahí), sino que la misma se haría con datos nuevos los cuales se supone ya tienes a mano por otra vía. Y si usaras datos que ya existen para actualizar esos mismos datos, entonces es que tienes un gravísimo error de diseño en tu programa.

@A.Cedano como siempre es un gusto leer tus aportaciones y tu visión es muy acertada, ya di con la solución era digamos algo sencillo, pero a veces se pierde uno en el bosque.  Ya realiza lo que necesitaba. Saludos

Saludos
Te sugiero lo siguiente:
if($num == 1)
   {return TRUE;}
elseif ($num == 0)
   {return FALSE;}

que sea:
return $num>0;

En la parte donde tienes:
if($this->consulta_dgenerales() == FALSE ){
   $this->guardar_generales();  //inserta datos 
   $this->actualizar_g();   //actualiza un campo en base a lo insertado
} elseif($this->consulta_dgenerales() == TRUE ) {
   $this->actualizar_a(); // actualiza datos previamente capturados
   $this->actualizar_g(); // actualiza un campo en base a la actualizacion
}

(estás buscando dos veces); que sea:
$consultadGenerales = $this->consulta_dgenerales();
if($consultadGenerales == FALSE ){
   $this->guardar_generales();  //inserta datos 
   $this->actualizar_g();   //actualiza un campo en base a lo insertado
} elseif($consultadGenerales == TRUE ) {
   $this->actualizar_a(); // actualiza datos previamente capturados
   $this->actualizar_g(); // actualiza un campo en base a la actualizacion
}

También toma en cuenta los comentario que han vertido respecto a la antigüedad del código e ir haciendo una migración a lo más reciente.

Bueno finalmente ya se pudo concretar la solución, tras varios intentos y cambiar una y otra vez el código. En la seccion de donde regresamos el valor obtenido que era esto:


`$resultado=mysql_query($consulta) or die
             $valor = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
             $num = $valor['VALOR'];
             echo $num;  <--- Aquí me regresa ya sea 1 o 0 es temporal para visualización del dato que se obtiene//
             if($num == 1)
                {return TRUE;}
             elseif ($num == 0)
                {return FALSE;}
        }` 



Se modifico a esto:


  if ($resultado) {
        $total = mysql_fetch_row($resultado);

        if ($total && isset($total[0])) {
            $this->valor_generales = $total[0];
        } else {
            $this->valor_generales = 0; // Valor predeterminado si no hay registros
        }

        echo "La cantidad de registros es: " . $this->valor_generales; //Esto se podria eliminar no es tan necesario pero para control de momento es una buena idea. 
        return $total;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}



Ya con el cambio en la estructura de código en la forma de recibir y manipular los datos es que finalmente obtuve lo que necesito.  Como bien dice Cedano, solo necesitaba validar si existe o no un registro.
Si no existe entonces hay que agregarlo, y si ya existe se invoca la función para realizar una actualización de los datos.  Hice otra función para mandar llamar en base a los datos obtenidos las acciones que se requerian


public function cargar_datos_generales(){
            
                if ($this->valor_generales == 1){
                    
                echo ("Que valor traer primer IF: ". $this->valor_generales); // Esto se borrara posteriormente//
                $this->actualizar_alumno_datos_ubicacion();
                $this->actualizar_direccion_generales();
                }
                elseif($this->valor_generales == 0){
                    
                echo ("Que valor traer segundo IF: ". $this->valor_generales); // Esto se borrara posteriormente//
                $this->guardar_datos_generales();
                $this->actualizar_direccion_generales();
                    
                
            }
            
        }



Con esta implementación ya regresa el valor requerido, y hace las acciones que se pretendían.
Por si alguna persona le sirve esta solución. Saludos. -Gracias-
